# simple way to download all Email addresses from all orders on 1.9.1 and 1.3.1?

Tags: order-email

I searched around to find a solution to this and I tried some but they didn't work. I am more and more thinking about doing this from phpmyadmin. Is that the easiest way to download all Emails from all orders you think?

I have 2 systems I need to do this from:

- an old 1.3.1
- and a newer 1.9.1

What would the database fields in phpMyAdmin be called?

I am not against any other solution as long as it works...

Comment: Re 1.9.1 Have you tried going to php myadmin and running this query yet? SELECT DISTINCT(o.customer_email) FROM sales_flat_order o

Comment: Sorry I missed the 'as'

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT(o.customer_email) FROM sales_flat_order AS o`

Comment: @Andy Myers I did that on the 1.9.1 and it gave me the following Error in php myAdmin:  #1146 - Table 'flower_flower.sales_flat_order' doesn't exist

Comment: @Andy Myers oh sorry - I had to do it like this: SELECT DISTINCT(o.customer_email) FROM mg_sales_flat_order AS o

Comment: @Andy Myers Any chance that could work on the old system too? It's still up and running = Magento 1.3.1 Thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a simple script within magento installation and grab those data.

Create a file called `export_data.php` in magento root.

Then add this code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); // enable all errors
require_once ("./app/Mage.php");
umask(0);
Mage::app("default"); // load the app

$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
          ->addAttributeToSelect('customer_email'); //select only customer email

foreach($orders as $order){
    echo $order->getCustomerEmail(). "<br>"; //print all emails in browser
}
```

This should work.

To generate data in csv:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); // enable all errors
require_once ("./app/Mage.php");
umask(0);
Mage::app("default"); // load the app

$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
          ->addAttributeToSelect('customer_email'); //select only customer email
  $outputFile = "order-customer-email.csv";
  $write = fopen($outputFile, 'w');
  foreach($orders as $order){
    fputcsv($write, $order->getCustomerEmail());
  }
  fclose($write);
  echo "File written at /var/export";
```

Comment: I created a file called: "export_data.php" and I put the code into it. I uploaded it to the root of my Magento store. I got the following Error when I accessed it in the browser (via www.mystore.com/export_data.php): error_reporting(E_ALL); // enable all errors require_once ("./app/Mage.php"); umask(0); Mage::app("default"); // load the app $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection() ->addAttributeToSelect('customer_email'); //select only customer email foreach($orders as $order){ echo $order->getCustomerEmail(). "
"; //print all emails in browser }

Comment: ...then I chmod the file 777 and now i just get the generic 404 message when accessing www.mystore.com/export_data.php

Comment: And how can I add the CSV part to it? Just tag it at the end of the file?

Comment: You needed to add `<?php` tag at the beginning. Check my update.

Comment: Thank you Adarsh! :o) If I want to get it in the CSV format - would I just paste both of those parts you posted together?

Comment: No, just copy the last one and generated file will be in you `var/export` folder.